# Correct use of a development (a.k.a. validation) set with PredefinedSplit and GridSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, validation, scoring-rules

I'm dealing with a classical machine learning classification task. I'm using the `sklearn` library.

My question is about the correct use of the test, development (can be intended as validation?) and train data with some API function of the library in the following example:

```
# given X_train, X_dev, X_test as data and y_train, y_dev, y_test as labels 

validation_set_indexes = [-1]*len(X_train) + [0]*len(X_dev)
ps = sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit(test_fold=validation_set_indexes)

search = ms.GridSearchCV(
  cv=ps,
  estimator=..., param_grid=..., scoring=...
)

search.fit(X_train+X_dev,y_train+y_dev)
y_test_pred = search.predict(X_test)
```

In particular:

- It is correct to use development set as validation set? Are they the same or not?
- Does the PredefinedSplit do what I intended? i.e. Use X_dev as validation set in the grid search? [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#predefined-fold-splits-validation-sets) it is explained the use of zeros and ones;
- It is correct to predict `y_test_pred` directly with the object return by `GridSearchCV` (`search` in the example)? Or do I need to do something like the following:

  ```
  # pick the best parameters found by the grid search
  best_param_1 = search.best_params_["param_1"]
  best_param_2 = search.best_params_["param_2"]
  ...

  new_model = model(param_1=best_param_1, param_2=best_param_2,...)
  new_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)
  ```

  In other words, use the grid search only for finding the best parameters for the scoring function and then run again the fitting of the model **only** on the training set?